# What are Eff and Aff?

Tags: purescript

What is the relationship between the Purescript types [`Eff`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-eff/0.1.2/docs/Control.Monad.Eff#t:Eff) and [`Aff`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff/0.16.1/docs/Control.Monad.Aff#t:Aff)? Is it possible to convert between them?

I'm just starting out with Purescript coming from Haskell, and it seems like both types roughly serve the role that `IO` has in Haskell. Is that fair to say?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`Eff` is a synchronous effect monad. It is used to sequence effectful foreign JavaScript code - things like random number generation, reading and writing mutable values, writing to the console and throwing and catching exceptions.

`Aff` is an asynchronous effect monad. It can handle and sequence effectful asynchronous code, like AJAX requests, timeouts, and network and file IO. It can also perform synchronous effects by using `liftEff`. And it also provides a nice mechanism for handling errors.

It is possible to convert from `Eff` to `Aff` using `liftEff` (everything which doesn't pause is an instance of something which is allowed to pause), but the other direction is not possible in general. `Aff` actions can be run in an `Eff` context by providing a callback.

Haskell's `IO` is similar to both, but closer to `Aff` than `Eff` in that `IO` actions can represent asynchronous things (see `threadDelay` for example).

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning `launchAff` which can be used to run an `Aff` computation synchronously if need be. It is defined in `Control.Monad.Aff`. Pursuit will have a better description of what it does and how it works than I can fit in a comment.